# What's the difference between group roles and login roles?

Tags: postgresql, security

It looks like for single user I should create a login role and than respective group roles because I can't directly assign privileges on login role. Is it true? What's the purpose of such separation?

Also as I understand it's only possible to authenticate with **login role**. So what's the purpose of the password field in a **group role**? Or it's possible to authenticate as group role? Then why anyone would need login roles?

Also it looks like I can set both login and group roles in pg_hba.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All these questions are basically answered in the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html).  To be specific:

> A role is an entity that can own database objects and have database privileges; a role can be considered a "user", a "group", or both depending on how it is used.

That implies that internally there is no difference between these, except the `LOGIN` option.  If you specify `LOGIN` (or use `CREATE USER`):

```
CREATE ROLE dezso WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'bla';
```

`dezso` will become a login role, otherwise not.  You can specify passwords for non-login roles, too - if you later decide to make it a login role, use

```
CREATE ROLE non_login_role PASSWORD 'bla';

--later
ALTER ROLE non_login_role WITH LOGIN;
```

You are right when saying *'it's only possible to authenticate with login role'*.  Note, however, that a password is not always necessary - if you use anything else than the [`password` or `md5`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/role-attributes.html) authentication methods.  On the other hand this means that a role without the `LOGIN` option set cannot log in in any way.

Finally, you may set rules in `pg_hba.conf` for non-login roles, but as it's used only for authentication, those roles will have no effect (unless you enable login later, as above).

Comment: Why can't I assign table privileges for login roles in pgAdmin? Only group roles are listed there.

Comment: It must be some design issue/bug - I was wondering myself.  Such issues are the reasons why I am exclusively using `psql` and normal SQL statements for everything.